# Cannot find name after typing a named function

Tags: javascript, typescript

After defining an interface for a named function ts no longer sees the actual function ?

```
interface InitiatePlayers {
    (this: App, arg0: { amount: string }): void;
}

<InitiatePlayers>function initiatePlayers({ amount }) {
    const PlayerWidth = this.width / 45;
    this.nodes.push(
        PlayerFactory({ width: PlayerWidth }),
        PlayerFactory({ width: PlayerWidth, id: 'player-2', x: this.width - PlayerWidth })
    );
};

app.onInit = function () {
    // Add Players to the board
    initiatePlayers.call(this, { amount: 2 }); // cannot find name of function
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the `<InitiatePlayers>` syntax mess it up.

The [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwQLjmAnjAvDA3gXwG4AoYgSzCgFMAnAMzmCpgEkwyoy5qAFAGzjpaEPMRjiYACigALMhGTwMAGng0A5gAZFueAFsQAV0qLoNCupj4AlIoBuIMgBMS+UqEiwKHLrwFCaBVZ2Tm4qfkFhbBg6Y2BOcCldMX0jSmViG1FMkmJEBAA6cDYOaNiweLJEyWtRcW9Qv0jAguA4Pj5pOQhVXTgDYyhFACYra1diIA) detects correctly the type of the function :

```
const app:any = {};

interface InitiatePlayers {
    (this: any, arg0: { amount: string }): void;
}

const initiatePlayers: InitiatePlayers = function ({ 
  amount,
}) {

};

app.onInit = function () {
  initiatePlayers.call(this, { amount: 2 });
}
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, I also "fixed" it by putting the function into a variable and "anonymizing" it. So this seems like a bug in TypeScript ? If so I'll submit an issue on GitHub

Comment: @Twiggeh I knew that the syntax exist but I can't find it's documentation ... Do you know how is it called ? `<foo> function bar() {`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT it's called "type assertion"

Comment: @Twiggeh I'd advise you to make absolutely sure this *is* a bug. I don't know whether a type assertion is allowed there. It might just be invalid syntax. I've not encountered this style of giving a type to a function. It might be valid but I don't really know of any instances when it's used.